# Transform data by-group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want know if it is possible to apply ggplot2 transformations (of data) *after* grouping has been performed.

Example:

Here is a qqplot of `iris` by species:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(sample=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) +
    stat_qq() +
    ggtitle('qqnorm of Sepal Width')
```

[image: qqnorm raw sepal width]

I want to transform the `Sepal.Width`s by `(x - mean(x))/sd(x)`:

```
normalize = function (x) (x - mean(x))/sd(x)
ggplot(iris, aes(sample=normalize(Sepal.Width), col=Species)) +
    stat_qq() +
    ggtitle('qqnorm of Sepal Width, normalized globally')
```

[image: qqnorm of sepal width, shifted/scaled by global mean/sd]

Note that this has used the global mean/sd in normalizing, not the per-group mean/sd (same happens if you write `aes(sample=(Sepal.Width - mean(Sepal.Width))/sd(Sepal.Width))` rather than hiding it away in `normalize`.

**Question**: is there a way to apply `normalize` **within** each group (Species)?

I can do it with `ddply`, just wondered if there was an elegant way to apply an affine transformation to my data in the `ggplot` call, where the transformation parameters are per-group.

```
ggplot(ddply(iris, .(Species), mutate, y=normalize(Sepal.Width)),
             aes(sample=y, col=Species)) +
    stat_qq() +
    ggtitle('qqnorm of Sepal.Width, normalized within-group')
```

[image: qqnorm I'm after]

Comment: FYI: just discovered the in-built function `scale`: `scale(x)` is the same as my `normalize(x)`.

Comment: I'm not sure, but: `ggplot(iris, aes(sample=Sepal.Width, col=Species)) + stat_qq(distribution=function(p) qnorm(scale(p)))` ?

Comment: @BenBolker unfortunately no, `qnorm` takes in a set of quantiles and returns normal values (on the 'theoretical' axis). I need to modify the 'sample' axis. Suspect `ddply` might end up being the way to go, the more I look at it the less unwieldy it seems.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just change the function `normalize` to take an argent `by`. That makes the `normalize` function more complicated, but simplifies the `ggplot` call (compared to the `plyr` solution). See below for my suggestion on how to define normalize.

```
# new normalize command
normalize <- function(x, by='none'){
  unsplit(lapply(unique(by), function(id) scale(x[by==id])), by)
} 
# global normalization
ggplot(iris, aes(sample=normalize(Sepal.Width), col=Species)) +
  stat_qq() +
  ggtitle('qqnorm of Sepal Width, normalized globally')
# groupe-wise normalization
ggplot(iris, aes(sample=normalize(Sepal.Width, by=Species), col=Species)) +
  stat_qq() +
  ggtitle('qqnorm of Sepal Width, normalized by species')
```